# Best way to strip out a NL

Tags: c

I tried this but it's not working for me:

```
char * remove_nl(char * newstr)
{
    newstr = strdup(newstr);
    newstr[strlen(newstr)-1] = '\0';
    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: When you duplicate an uninitialized pointer, you get random garbage.  How do you know there is a newline in the string that `newstr` points to between the first two lines of code...you should show some initialization there somehow.

Comment: @Jonathan, I've updated it.  The newstr actually comes in as a return of asctime() so it's supposed to end in '\n'

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: If it is strictly from `asctime()`, then you know exactly how long the string is and don't absolutely have to do the `strlen()` operation.  On the other hand, it is safer to do as you have done.  (The extra context improves your question noticeably.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have now is fine, except:

1. you have to make sure that `newstr` points to a valid string;
2. check that `strlen(newstr) > 0`;
3. check that `newstr[strlen(newstr)-1]` is indeed a newline before wiping it;
4. make sure the caller `free()`s the returned string.